# Warning: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working s3 amazon to upload file.

I found sdk here [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease--net-31](http://here)

its working fine when i run this code separately. When i integrate this code with CI i am getting

**Warning: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: C:\xampp\tmp\phpE746.tmp**

and its not uploading file.
Can anyone have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs when you try to send a file larger than allowed in the upload_max_filesize or post_max_size.

The default in etc/php.ini is:

```
; http://php.net/post-max-size

post_max_size = 2M
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Make sure the file is not larger than allowed, it may be that.

Also check this passing the full path.